# How replace an old image for another new image in django models?

Tags: django

I want to replace old image from django models by new image.

This is my models.py:

```
class ProfileImage(models.Model):
    image_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', null=True, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

okey i assume that you struggling with that, i was in the same situation before, when i update the image field with a new image the image did change but the file is always there in my images folder.

So in your case i will assume that you cannot change the image with a new one, because when editing a model that contain image you can not user

```
ProfileImage.objects.update(profile_image=new_image)
```

this will not work with django.

So first what you have to do is to get the desired object like so

```
#get the object
old_image = ProfileImage.objects.filter(your fiter here)

#and then update it with the new image
new_image = request.FILES[the name of the file that will be sent from the client form]
old_image.profile_image = new_image
old_image.save()
```

and now to delete the old image from the images folder i really recommend you to use 
[django-cleanup](https://pypi.org/project/django-cleanup/)
that will do the hard code in your behalf and it will be applied to all the future image file fields do you have just to worry about the object's updates.

Comment: Thank you so much.. But ProfileImage.objects.update(profile_image=new_image) its work in django 2.2

Comment: when trying the solution provided what result do you have ?

Comment: Sorry you are right. If i do use ProfileImage.objects.update(profile_image=new_image) the image path was changed. But when i do make  queries the path did not found. I do think it is django bugs. Again i say thank you so much.......

Answer (score 1):

add dependency `pip install django-cleanup`
this will deletes old files after updating,

---

then add it your apps

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...,
    'django_cleanup.apps.CleanupConfig',
)
```

[checkout the package django-cleanup](https://pypi.org/project/django-cleanup/)